# Combine two pandas series, dropping na values

Tags: python, pandas, merge

Given two pandas series, with non overlapping na values and values, how to merge them into a single series

example

```py
s1 = pd.Series([1, 2, 3, np.nan])
s2 = pd.Series([np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 99])
```

output

```py
# F(s1, s2) returns:
0    1.0
1    2.0
2    3.0
3    99.0
dtype: float64
```

## Edit

It seems that

```py
s1.combine_first(s2)
```

Satisfies the above (should I delete this post?)

Comment: safe to delete if ur question is already answered

Comment: You shouldn't delete answers unless they are duplicates, for people with the same issues you had

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can combine two series as follows:

```
s1.combine_first(s2)
```